# Numeros basura al almacenar datos en structura y luego perdirlos Lenguaje C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi escuela, practimanete ya lo termine pero no se por que no se guardan los numeros que le doy en el momento de ingresarlos y al mostrarlos me salen otros diferentes

1. Primero se registran los Alumnos en la opcion uno puden registrase maximo 10
   [image]
2. En la segunda opcion de mostrar, te muestra los daatos del ultimo alumno registrado (aqui esta el problema)
   [image]
3. En la tercera opcion se busca a los alumnos del 1 al 10 la secuencia
   que los guardaste y te imprime sus datos(aqui se reite el problema)
   [image]
   [image]
   **Mi Codigo**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//variable contador de alumons
int contador1  = 0;

//acentos y ñ
char n = 164;
char a = 160;
char e = 130;
char ii = 161;
char o = 162;
char u = 163;

//estructura de busqueda
struct menuCaptura // structura principal de codigo
{
    struct agenda // nombre de la estructura
    {   // inicio de la estructura
    char nombre[40], domicilio[30], fracc[30],ciudad[25],e_m[20],notas[20];
    int  telefono[20],cp[6];
    }ag[10];  //Alias
    struct academia // nombre de la estructura
    {   // inicio de la estructura
    char  carrera[30],escuela[6];
    int   codigo[3],promedio[25], semestre[30];
}ac[10];  //Alias
}menCap;

//funcion para cordednadads
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon, dwPos);
}

//programa principal
int main(){

   /*marco(1);
    marcoCarga(0);
    claveInicio();
    cargaLogo();
    */
    //Menu principal y selector de opciones
    menu();


    return 0;
}


//Funciones............

//funcion de marco
void marco(tiempo)
{


    int tiempoMarco = tiempo;
    int i;
    system("COLOR 02");

    for(i=1;i<30;i++){ //lateral derecho
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(3,i);
        printf("%c",219);
    }
    for(i=4;i<50;i++){  //Superior
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(i,1);
        printf("%c",223);
    }
        for(i=1;i<30;i++){  // lateral derecho
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(50,i);
        printf("%c",219);
    }
    for(i=4;i<50;i++){  // Inferior
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(i,29);
        printf("%c",220);
    }
    return 0;
}

//funcon carga con marco
void marcoCarga(tiempo)
{
    int contador, vueltas = 0;
    int tiempoMarco = tiempo;
    int i;
    do{
    system("COLOR 02");

    for(i=1;i<29;i++){ //lateral derecho
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(3,i);
        printf("%c",219);
    }
    for(i=4;i<50;i++){  //Superior
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(i,1);
        printf("%c",223);
    }
        for(i=1;i<29;i++){  // lateral derecho
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(50,i);
        printf("%c",219);
    }
    for(i=4;i<50;i++){  // Inferior
        Sleep(tiempoMarco);
        gotoxy(i,28);
        printf("%c",220);
    }
    gotoxy(20,14.5);
    printf("Cargando");
    for (contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++)
    {
        putchar('.');
        _sleep(250);
    }
        vueltas = vueltas + 1;
    system("cls");
    }while(vueltas <= 2);
    return 0;
}

//funcion de clave inicio de programa
void claveInicio()
{
    int claveCorrecta = 123;
    int claveRegistro = 0;
    int intentos = 0;
    do{
    system("cls");
    marco(0);
    gotoxy(32,27);
    printf("Intentos %i de 3", intentos);
    gotoxy(5,5);
    printf("Por favor ingrese su clave: ");
    scanf("%i", &claveRegistro);
        if(claveRegistro != claveCorrecta){
            gotoxy(5,6);
            printf("Contrase%ca incorrecta, intentelo otra vez\n", n);
            gotoxy(32,27);
            printf("Intentos %i de 3", intentos + 1);
            intentos = intentos + 1;
            Sleep(2000);
        }
        else{
            gotoxy(5,6);
            printf("Contrase%ca correcta, por favor espere...", n);
            intentos = 4;
            Sleep(2000);
            system("cls");
        }
    }while(intentos < 3);
    return 0;
}

//funcion de cargando
void carga(){
    int contador, vueltas = 0;
    do{
    printf("\nCargando");
    for (contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++)
    {
        putchar('.');
        _sleep(500);
    }
        vueltas = vueltas + 1;
    system("cls");
    }while(vueltas <= 5);
}

//funcion logo udg
void logo()
{
    system("cls");
        printf("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWWWWWWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM\nMMMMMMMW0xdddddddONMMMMMKxdxdxxddONMWKoclllllllllllllloodk0NWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWX0OxxdddxkOKXWMMMMMMMM\nMMMMMWOc..cddddo;,OMMMWk;.:ddddo;,OWO;.:O0000000000000OkdlcclkXMMMMMMMMMMWXkolooddxxkxxdoolldONMMMMM\nMMMWOc.. 'OMMMMWo,OMMMX:.'kMMMMWo,OWd..lNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKdc:xXMMMMMMW0ocokKNWMMMMMMMMMWN0xlcxXMMM\nMMMNOxl' 'OMMMMWo,OMMMX:.'kMMMMWo,OWd..lNMMMMWKOOOO00KXWMMMMMNx;c0MMMMXo:dKWMMMMWNXKKKXNWMMMMNd,oNMM\nMMMMMMK; 'OMMMMWo,OMMMX:.'kMMMMWo,OWd..lNMMMM0;.......,:xXMMMMW0::0MWO:c0WMMMWXxl;,'..',cdKN0oco0WMM\nMMMMMMK; 'OMMMMWo,OMMMX:.'kMMMMWo,OWd..lNMMMM0,,loolc,...;0WMMMWk,oXk,:KMMMMNx:coxkkkxl;..';cdKWMMMM\nMMMMMMK; 'OMMMMWo,OMMMX:.'kMMMMWo,OWd..lNMMMM0;lNMMMWXx,..cXMMMMX:;d;'kWMMMWd;xWMMMMMMMNOlcdKWWWMMMM\nMMMMMMK; 'OMMMMWo,OMMMX: 'kMMMMWo,OWd..lNMMMM0;lNMMMMMWx..:KMMMMXc,;.;0MMMMK:lNMMMMMMMWKoloooolo0MMM\nMMMMMMK; 'OMMMMWo,kMMMX:.'OMMMMNo,OWd..lNMMMM0;lNMMMMMMk'.oNMMMMK;,,.;KMMMM0:oNMMMMMMM0;.oXXXXx;dWMM\nMMMMMMK: .xWMMMMk,lXMMK:.:KMMMMXc;0Wd..lNMMMM0,:0KKK0Ox:,oXMMMMWd,oc.'OMMMMNl:0WMMMMMMk..xMMMMO;dWMM\nMMMMMMNl..cXMMMMNx:cloc,c0WMMMWk,lNWd..lNMMMMXocllllllokKWMMMMNd,oXx..lXMMMMKl:xXMMMMMk..xWMMMO;dWMM\nMMMMMMWk'..lXMMMMMNKOO0KWMMMMWO;:KMWd..lNMMMMMWWWWWWWMMMMMMMNOc;xNMK:..oNMMMMNkllodxxxc.,kWMMMO;dWMM\nMMMMMMMNd...;kXWMMMMMMMMMMMWKo;lKMMWd..lNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXOo;'c0WMMM0:..:OWMMMMWXOkxdxxOKWMMMMO;dWMM\nMMMMMMMMNx,...,lxO0KXXXK0kd:';xNMMMWd..,looooooooooooll:;'.'cONMMMMMMXo...ckXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXOc:OMMM\nMMMMMMMMMWXx:'......'''...':xXMMMMMWx'................';cokXWMMMMMMMMMW0l,..'coxOKKXXXK0Oxoc;:dKWMMM\nMMMMMMMMMMMMWKkdolcccclodOKWMMMMMMMMN0OOOOOOOOOOOOO00KXNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXko:,....''''',,;ld0NMMMMMM\nMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXKOkxxxkkOKXWMMMMMMMMMM\nMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM");
    return 0;
}

//funcion carga con logo
void cargaLogo()
{
    void carga();
    int contador, vueltas = 0;
    do{
    logo();
    printf("\nCargando");
    for (contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++)
    {
        putchar('.');
        _sleep(250);
    }
        vueltas = vueltas + 1;
    system("cls");
    }while(vueltas <= 5);
}

//funcion de pantalla principal
void menu()
{
        bool bucleMenu = TRUE;
    do{
        int opcionMenus;
        opcionMenus = 0;
        system("cls");
        marcoCarga(0);
        system("cls");
        marco(0);
        gotoxy(25,2);
        printf("Men%c", u);
        gotoxy(11,7);
        printf("1-Capturar");
        gotoxy(11,8);
        printf("2-Mostrar");
        gotoxy(11,9);
        printf("3-Buscar");
        gotoxy(11,10);
        printf("4-Salir");
        gotoxy(13,13);
        printf("Elige una Opci%cn Num%crica: ", o,e);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i", &opcionMenus);
        if (opcionMenus == 1)
        {
        bucleMenu = TRUE;
        captura();
        }
        if (opcionMenus == 2)
        {
        bucleMenu = TRUE;
        mostrar();
        }
        if (opcionMenus == 3)
        {
        bucleMenu = TRUE;
        buscar();
        }
        if(opcionMenus == 4)
        {
            system("cls");
            marco(0);
            gotoxy(10,15);
            printf("Gracias por utilizar el programa\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n  ");
            bucleMenu = FALSE;
        }
    }while(bucleMenu == TRUE);
    return 0;
}



//funcion de mostrar
void mostrar()
{
    system("cls");
    marcoCarga(0);
    system("cls");
    marco(0);
    gotoxy(19,2);
    printf("DATOS PERSONALES");// Datos personales
    gotoxy(4,3);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(4,13);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(19,14);
    printf("DATOS ACADEMICOS");// Datos Academicos
    gotoxy(4,15);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(5,5);
    printf("Nombre: %s",menCap.ag[contador1].nombre);
    gotoxy(5,6);
    printf("Domicilio: %s",menCap.ag[contador1].domicilio);
    gotoxy(5,7);
    printf("Fraccionamiento: %s",menCap.ag[contador1].fracc);
    gotoxy(5,8);
    printf("C%cdigo Postal: %i", o,menCap.ag[contador1].cp);
    gotoxy(5,9);
    printf("Ciudad: %s",menCap.ag[contador1].ciudad);
    gotoxy(5,10);
    printf("T%clefono del Alumno: %i", e, menCap.ag[contador1].telefono);
    gotoxy(5,11);
    printf("Correo: %s", menCap.ag[contador1].e_m);
    gotoxy(5,12);
    printf("Notas: %s", menCap.ag[contador1].notas);
    gotoxy(5,17);
    printf("Codigo: %i", menCap.ac[contador1].codigo);
    gotoxy(5,18);
    printf("Carrera: %s", menCap.ac[contador1].carrera);
    gotoxy(5,19);
    printf("Semestre: %i", menCap.ac[contador1].semestre);
    gotoxy(5,20);
    printf("Escuela: %s", menCap.ac[contador1].escuela);
    gotoxy(5,21);
    printf("Promedio: %i", menCap.ac[contador1].promedio);
    Sleep(5000);
    return menu();
}
//funcion de busqueda de datos
void buscar()
{
    int contador2;
    system("cls");
    marcoCarga(0);
    system("cls");
    marco(0);
    gotoxy(19,2);
    printf("Alumno a buscar: ");
    scanf("%i", &contador2);
    gotoxy(19,2);
    printf("DATOS PERSONALES");// Datos personales
    gotoxy(4,3);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(4,13);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(19,14);
    printf("DATOS ACADEMICOS");// Datos Academicos
    gotoxy(4,15);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(5,5);
    printf("Nombre: %s",menCap.ag[contador2].nombre);
    gotoxy(5,6);
    printf("Domicilio: %s",menCap.ag[contador2].domicilio);
    gotoxy(5,7);
    printf("Fraccionamiento: %s",menCap.ag[contador2].fracc);
    gotoxy(5,8);
    printf("C%cdigo Postal: %i", o,menCap.ag[contador2].cp);
    gotoxy(5,9);
    printf("Ciudad: %s",menCap.ag[contador2].ciudad);
    gotoxy(5,10);
    printf("T%clefono del Alumno: %i", e, menCap.ag[contador2].telefono);
    gotoxy(5,11);
    printf("Correo: %s", menCap.ag[contador2].e_m);
    gotoxy(5,12);
    printf("Notas: %s", menCap.ag[contador2].notas);
    gotoxy(5,17);
    printf("Codigo: %i", menCap.ac[contador2].codigo);
    gotoxy(5,18);
    printf("Carrera: %s", menCap.ac[contador2].carrera);
    gotoxy(5,19);
    printf("Semestre: %i", menCap.ac[contador2].semestre);
    gotoxy(5,20);
    printf("Escuela: %s", menCap.ac[contador2].escuela);
    gotoxy(5,21);
    printf("Promedio: %i", menCap.ac[contador2].promedio);
    Sleep(5000);
    return menu();
}
//funcion de captura de datos
void captura()
{
    system("cls");
    marcoCarga(0);
    contador1++;
    system("cls");
    marco(0);
    gotoxy(19,2);
    printf("DATOS PERSONALES");// Datos personales
    gotoxy(4,3);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(4,13);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(19,14);
    printf("DATOS ACADEMICOS");// Datos Academicos
    gotoxy(4,15);
    printf("----------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(5,5);
    printf("Nombre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(menCap.ag[contador1].nombre);
    gotoxy(5,6);
    printf("Domicilio: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(menCap.ag[contador1].domicilio);
    gotoxy(5,7);
    printf("Fraccionamiento: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(menCap.ag[contador1].fracc);
    gotoxy(5,8);
    printf("C%cdigo Postal: ", o);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i", menCap.ag[contador1].cp);
    gotoxy(5,9);
    printf("Ciudad: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(menCap.ag[contador1].ciudad);
    gotoxy(5,10);
    printf("T%clefono del Alumno: ", e);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i",menCap.ag[contador1].telefono);
    gotoxy(5,11);
    printf("Correo: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(menCap.ag[contador1].e_m);
    gotoxy(5,12);
    printf("Notas: " );
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(menCap.ag[contador1].notas);
    gotoxy(5,17);
    printf("Codigo: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i",menCap.ac[contador1].codigo);
    gotoxy(5,18);
    printf("Carrera: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(menCap.ac[contador1].carrera);
    gotoxy(5,19);
    printf("Semestre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i",menCap.ac[contador1].semestre);
    gotoxy(5,20);
    printf("Escuela: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets( menCap.ac[contador1].escuela);
    gotoxy(5,21);
    printf("Promedio: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i",menCap.ac[contador1].promedio);
    return menu();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al acabar tus subprogramas con `return menu();` (debería ser `return;` para volver) tu creas un bucle infinito de llamadas a `menu()`; cada llamada borra todo lo que había antes en la pantalla y escribe por arriba; no es un funcionamiento correcto. También en un menú normal debe haber una posibilidad de salida sin hacer nada.

Luego el problema de tu programa es que en ningún momento empezaste a contar los alumnos desde 0. Se registran desde 0, perfecto; 10 alumnos, hasta 9, perfecto; `contador1` vale 10 en este momento. Llames a `mostrar()`, la cual cosa imprime el alumno `[10]`; que no se ha registrado.

Pero aún, dado que `men.ac` tiene un tamaño de 10 elementos y no hay ningún control de límite (una cosa indispensable en C), `men.ac[10]` no existe y estas leyendo memoria que no pertenece a tu programa. Aquí tienes hasta suerte de leer *algo*; normalmente el programa se debería parar con error de segmentación.